# SSIS Log Provider not working with SQL Server User

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

I have created a SIS Log Provider to write a log entry from a Script Task in a SSIS package. The connection is working a long as I use Windows Authentication, but if I switch to SQL Server Authentication and provide a username and a password no log entry is written. I use the same connection in the package to execute a SQL Task to read from the SSIS Log with no problem. The SQL Server User has read and write access to the SSIS Log.

I have to use SQL Server Authentication because the Windows User Running the SSIS Job and the package doesn't have access to SSIS Log and this could not be changed.
I'm using VS SSDT 2017 and deploy the package to SQL Server 2016.

I tried to store the username and password in the package and to provide the connectionstring and password via package parameters and environment.
No effect as soon as I switch from Windows Authentication to SQL Server Authentication.

```
Dts.Log(logMessage, 0, emptyBytes);
```

The above code should write an entry in the SSIS Log, but works only for Windows Authentication.

Edit: 
The SSIS Log Provider Type is **SSIS log provider for SQL Server**. 

The connection manager type is OLEDB, the provider type is **Native OLE DB/SQL Server Native Client 11.0**.

The connection is parameterized for the connection string and the password.

Comment: Can you give us more details about the SSIS Log Provider you created? What's the provider type? How is the connection manager for the log file configured?